# AttributeError at /home/ 'list' object has no attribute 'resolve'

Tags: python, css, django

I keep getting a 'AttributeError at /home/ 'list' object has no attribute 'resolve'' error. I've changed the code in multiple ways and read the docs, but I'm still confused.

'python manage.py findstatic /file/css/syle.css' didn't help much either.

from urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from home import views

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [ patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^home/$', views.Home, name="home"),
    url(r'^services/$', views.Services, name="services"),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.Contact, name="contact")) 
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

from settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = 'home/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = 'sitename/home/static/css.js'

STATIC_DIRS = 'home/static'
```

project structure:

```
sitename
    db.sqlite3
    home
        __init.py
        admin.py
        models.py
        static
            home.html
            services.html
            contact.html
        views.py
    manage.py
    mysite
        __init.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
```

What am I missing?

Also, I'd love your recommendations for reference material.

from home.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block doctype %}<!DOCTYPE HTML>{% endblock %}
{% load i18n %}
<html> 
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}{% trans "title" %}</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        {% block meta_tags %}{% endblock %}
        <noscript>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-wide.css" />
        </noscript>
        {% block stylesheet %}{% endblock %}
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.doc.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/doc.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/doc-layers.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/init.js"></script>
        {% block js %}{% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body class="{% block bodyclass %}{% endblock%}">
        {% block page %}
            <div id="header">{% block header_navigation %}
                <h1><a href="LOGO.jpg" id="logo">{% trans "header/name of business" %}<em>content description</em></a></h1>
                    <nav id="nav">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="current"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{% url 'services' %}">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
            <section class="wrapper style1">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row 200%">
                        <section>
                            <p>content</p>

                            <p>content</p>

                            <p>content</p>              
                        </section>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <div id="footer">
                {% block footer %}
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <section class="3u 6u(narrower) 12u$(mobilep)">

                        </section>
                    {% endblock %}  
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="copyright">
                        <ul class="menu">
                            <li>&copy; All rights reserved</li><li>Adapted by: <a href="">me</a></li>, Original Design: <a href="">someone else</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

            </div>
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove square brackets around the `patterns()` and add [staticfiles_urlpatterns()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.urls.staticfiles_urlpatterns) to the `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^home/$', views.Home, name="home"),
    url(r'^services/$', views.Services, name="services"),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.Contact, name="contact")
) + staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Change settings to:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/absolute/path/to/static/dir/in/doc_root/'
# For example: /var/www/yoursite.com/static/
```

`STATIC_ROOT` should be set on production server.  Development server ignores this setting.

`STATIC_DIRS` is not required for your project layout.  Django automatically uses `static` directories in all apps from the `INSTALLED_APPS` as the source for static files.

To link to static assets you need to use the [`{% static %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static) template tag. For example instead of:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
```

code should be like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" />
```

BTW do not place templates into the static dir.  `manage.py collectstatic` will make source code of these templates available for everyone.  I suspect you don't want this :-)

Comment: This does fix the initial problem. Thank you! But I am now back to the previous problem, where I am getting 404s for every .js doc. I've tried adding the file paths directly like so: 
    STATIC_ROOT = 'sitename/home/static/css.js', 'sitename/home/static/css2.js' 
But that doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Even with 'http://localhost:8000/home/static/' as my STATIC_URL, I still only see text and links when I reload the local server page. (Also, you are awesome. Thank you very much for helping me.)

Comment: See the updated answer.  If place `style.css` into `home/static/css` directory and it will be available as `127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/style.css`

Comment: Note added `staticfiles_urlpatterns()` to your url patterns.

Comment: It's the .js docs I'm having trouble with. I can open them in the browser, but when I reload the local host I only see links and text still. I get path defined errors like '404 2459' and '404 2489' in the terminal when I refresh. This is after doing 'manage.py collectstatic'. :-/

Comment: You don't need to run `collectstatic` on the development server. This command is for production only.  And note the import of `staticfiles_urlpatterns` in the first line of my answer,

Comment: I've double checked my urls.py and settings.py and still only see texts and links. I've restarted my dev server as well. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "only see texts and links"?  And show your html template, please.

Comment: I've changed the names of some of the .js docs, if that matters.

Comment: You should use the `{% static %}` template tag - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static See the updated answer.

Comment: Hmmm... even with these changes I get a bunch of 304 and 404 errors when I reload. I'll have to take a closer look at the docs and see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

the return type of `static` is a list, you should expand it:

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    *static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT),
]
```